# 24V input shutdown-latch - is it a good idea?

Tags: transistors, latch, industrial

I want to protect my circuit by adding the ability to the MCU, to turn-off the power supply (and by this also turn itself off), in case of certain failure conditions are met. One of it would be excessive heat at some power components measured to prevent damage to the system.

As the SMPS I intend to use, is with a  \$\overline{SHDN}\$ pin, I want to latch this \$\overline{SHDN}\$ pin and by this turn-off the whole system. The user then would have to remove the power to reset the fault.
So I came up with the following circuit.

[image]
[image]

In a spice simulation, it works well. When V2 triggers the latch and turns on Q3, it remains latched under all conditions.

The environment is industrial, and the 24V input is provided by the user.

So I got some questions

- Is the overall concept a good idea, or does it introduce other concerns?
- In an noisy industrial environment, I would obviously not like the latch to latch unintended or the latch to fail and not latch / turn-off the system

  - Is this circuit ruggedized enough as shown, or would you suggest further measures to ruggedize it?
  - What could be the failure modes of this circuit and how could I improve on it?

Comment: A couple quick comments.  First, if the SHDN node/pin is active low, add an underscore in front of the label name to put a bar on top so it shows as \$\overline{\text{SHDN}}\$.  It prevents anyone looking at the schematic from having to make assumptions.  Second, the main thing that came to mind is to verify if the MCU GPIO pin doesn't default to a weak pullup state at any point between its powerup-reset sequence and until you get control to setup the pin a push/pull output.  If it does (even briefly) and you can't override it, you can put a stronger external pulldown resistor on the pin.

Comment: I changed the \$\overline{SHDN}\$ in text. The point with the soft-pull-up is a good one. I'll take that into acount.